# How to keep Django Flat Pages under version control?

Tags: django, django-flatpages, django-reversion

Django flatpages is a very basic CMS 
Django-reversions enables a backup of models past versions access in the admin https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion

How can I keep the flatpages app models under reversion? The models are not explicitly set in my code but come as a built in django feature that is autodiscovered by the admin.

Answer (score 1):

You can register third party models like this

```
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import Flatpage
from reversion.helpers import patch_admin

patch_admin(Flatpage)
```

[See docs](http://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin.html#admin)

Comment: I have tried that but got the error "ImportError: cannot import name Flatpage". I had that code in a 'base' app's models.py. Where is the appropriate place to call this?

Comment: Common place is `admin.py`. Could you provide full trace?